# How can I use an enum class that I created in an html page

Tags: java, html, enums

I have an enum class named "BlankEnm" and have a searchlayout.html page. How can i use enum velues in html page in `<select>` (`<option>`) tags. i want to see them in the select box (combo box)

I tried obuot the  th tags (`<th th:text="bla bla ">` ), but coudn't get any progress. It didn't work.

here is my enum class that i would like to use in the html page;

```
public enum BlankEnm {
ALL(0,"blankEnm.all"),
TITLE(1, "blankEnm.title"),
IDENTITY(2, "blankEnm.identity"),
TAXNUMBER(3, "blankEnm.taxNumber");


private final int id;
private final String text;

BlankEnm(int id, String text) {
    this.id = id;
    this.text = text;
}

public int id() {
    return this.id;
}

public String text() {
    return this.text;
}


public static int blankMapper(String blankChar) {
    switch (blankChar.toLowerCase()) {
        case "ü":
            return TITLE.id;
        case "k":
            return IDENTITY.id;
        case "v":
            return TAXNUMBER.id;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}


public static BlankEnm parseType(Integer value) {
    for (BlankEnm type : BlankEnm.values()) {
        if (value.equals(type.id())) {
            return type;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

I expect using my enum class elements in the html page in a select box

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to store the values of your Enum in a new class and than iterate throug an ArrayList with the different objects of your class in it.

Your Class:

```
public class Data {

private int id;
...

public Data(int id) {
this.id = id;
...
}

}
```

Array List:

```
ArrayList<Data> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Data(0));
...
```